# Why does this house have 240V outlets in all rooms?

Tags: electrical

A friend's house, in the USA, has 240V ("dryer") outlets in almost every room... even in the hallway. They have no idea why one of the previous owners would do that.

I have never heard of this before, nor can I google a reason why.

Why would someone do this? 240V heaters everywhere? A poor-man's EU adapter? It seems both absurd, and unsafe.

Comment: Unless wired poorly, doesn't seem unsafe.  I converted my stove outlet to a dryer outlet and plug a heater into it.  Do they measure correctly at 220v?

Comment: How big is the house /rooms? Are the outlets near windows? Window/through the wall AC units above a certain BTU will be 220.

Comment: Hold on, the average random human doesn't really have their NEMA receptacle table memorized.  Can you confirm which particular outlet type you are referring to?  Dryers are NEMA 10-30 or 14-30 and are very bulky.  Any chance they're 6-20?

Comment: Can you post photos of the receptacles in question please?

Comment: maybe for a grow-op

Comment: It could be possible that the previous owners came from another country and brought a bunch of 240VAC appliances with them and thought it was a lower cost solution to bring 240VAC to every room than the replace their appliances with 120VAC models.

Comment: I can't get to the house currently but next time I do, I'll post a picture. (new question?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this several times in the PNW higher wattage plug in heaters used to be very cheap.  In this case they used portable heaters, not safe in my opinion but legal, if they had 15 or 20 am devices there are different types of receptacles that are legal for 220-240 devices dryer receptacles are 30 amp and would not be legal for smaller loads but a portable heater would be legal.

Comment: Have seen this in fl... 240V outlets in multiple rooms for ac units+

Comment: I have seen 240 20amp but that is a different outlet than a dryer most of the “large” window units I have seen have been 240v 20 amp.